# jQuery: toggle content on header click

Tags: jquery

html:

```
<h3>PS elementum justo ligula</h3>

<div class="hide">elementum justo ligula, interdum scelerisque dui feugiat eget. Pellentesque at dignissim velit, eget volutpat lacus. Proin non metus eget quam efficitur maximus.
    <button class="hide">Close</button>
</div>

<h3>Justo ligula</h3>

<div class="hide">Pellentesque at dignissim velit, eget volutpat lacus. Proin non metus eget quam efficitur maximus. Nulla blandit eros eu placerat rhoncus. Quisque in faucibus nibh. Cras ultrices iaculis purus porta.
    <button class="hide">Close</button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("div.hide").hide();

$("h3").click(function () {
    $(this).next("div.hide").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("button.hide").click(function () {
    $(this).parents("div.hide").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

i managed to get it work.: http://jsfiddle.net/qodgmhnd/

i just want you to check: is there more elegant solution?

and i need to add one more thing: close previouse content than next header is also clicked. right now it closes than parent header or close button is clicked.

Comment: Instead of `parents()` use `parent()`. That's it. Nothing can be suggested here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use single click handler to achieve this. also you can traverse to immediate parent using `.parent()` with elements context:

```
$("button.hide,h3").click(function () {
 var target = $(this).is('h3') ? $(this).next("div.hide") : $(this).parent();
 target.slideToggle("slow");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j23sa9bm/)**